# How to set a column in an SP list to display a clickable link to it's items attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I set a column in an SP list to display a clickable link to it's items attachment. I understand it's not possible out of the box but I'm tantalisingly close to achieving it using the all new custom column formatting. I'm using this:

```
{
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": {
         "operator": "+",
         "operands": [
            "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",
            "@currentField"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Of course this JSON was copied straight from  MS guidance on custom column formatting. Any idea on how to get the wildcard/placeholder for the items attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon Doy created a unique solution by allowing users to click the paper clip icon to display the attachment selection. take a look here https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2014/11/17/sharepoint-2013online-attachment-viewer-enhancement/